Is it possible to run a script when a file is accessd?
I have a program that, every time when a it does something it re-reads its configuration file. I would like to replace that file with some kind of virtual file, which calls a script an generates the config data on the fly.
I cannot change the way the file is called, else i could just pipe the config data in.
So ever time my file "stuff.conf" is read, it should get the output of running stuff.sh.
Else i would have to rewrite this config periodically, but there could be hours or seconds between changes in the source data or reads from the program. So i would have to set the timer very low and would probably waste resources 90% of the time.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

is "a program" written in "a programming language" that can use inofity

You might be able to get the effect/behavior you want by replacing the file with a named pipe,  and then having a mechanism to rewrite it whenever possible.

Different ways of approaching it. Humans have wildly different understandings of the term "setting the time very low" than computers. Are we talking milliseconds here?

and, this hinges a lot on both the rates at which the config file gets read and the source data changes, AND on how the source data actually gets in – via network? an input device? is it like a dbus setting? If you add that information to your question, chances are I could improve my answer to more specifically address your specific problem. Currently, your problem is a bit undedefined. I also removed the [tag:access-control] from your tag list, because it's not part of your question?

A named pipe could be used for that:
#! /bin/sh -
fifo=/path/to/stuff.conf
generator() {
  /path/to/stuff.sh "$@"
}
while true; do
  mkfifo -- "$fifo.new" &&
    mv -f -- "$fifo.new" "$fifo" ||
    exit
  generator > "$fifo"
done

Opening a fifo in write-only mode like the shell does with > here before running generator hangs until another process opens it in read mode.
So generator will be started as soon as the program opens the file.
We create a new fifo every time (replaced atomically with mv) to avoid a second generator instance being started and feeding the output to the same pipe while the program hasn't finished reading the first output yet.
That assumes the program reads the file sequentially and that no other process is trying to read it at the same time.

Thanks alot, its exactly what i searched for. Especially having an example helps.


Is it possible to run a script when a file is accessd?

Yes, but if your program is the only "user" of the generated configuration file, much more efficient would be to have a part of your existing "program" respond to the inotify(7) interface within its main loop. When an IN_ACCESS event is encountered, it would read all the necessary files and perform other necessary operations to generate the configuration in the internal data structures kept in program's memory, then whenever it "does something", it would use the internal structures instead of reading any files.
Alternatively, you could just write out the file as part of the inotify(7) IN_ACCESS event handler. In that case, care should be taken to disable the event handler (or use IN_ONESHOT), or set an internal flag during the writing to the file.

That sounds interesting. I would have to read further into it. Thanks


Else i would have to rewrite this config periodically, but there could be hours or seconds between changes in the source data or reads from the program.

You shouldn't do that, anyways: overwriting the file, you're risking that it's getting reloaded while you write it, hence gets read in a state where it's invalid!
Instead, you'd go and write your desired configuration to a separate file (usually in the same directory), and then use mv (in Unix words, the rename system call) to atomically replace the whole old with a complete new config file.
Now,

but there could be hours or seconds between changes in the source data

So, do the replacement only when the source data changes, not "always"? That seems to me to be the obvious thing to do here.
Simply have a background job (a "daemon") that watches the source data (however that works! Often, you don't have to watch, you can get notified about changes and can just let your program sleep until then). And when, and only when, it changes, that triggers the writing out of a new (temporary) config file, and the replacement of the existing one.
Now, if this happens every couple of seconds: that's basically eternity for a computer, so unless you have actually benchmarked this and it turns out to be very resource hungry, … don't worry about it being very resource-hungry? Human and computer time scales are so different that humans often worry about things that really take so minute time of a computer that it really doesn't matter.
Generally, from a system design point of view, your program reading the config file is a consumer of data that aperiodically checks for new data (namely, when it reads the config file).

If you have a side in this data source – data consumer that can actively trigger the process of an update by notifying your data mediary: Doing nothing until that updating happens is of course the best strategy for keeping load low (again, this might be very secondary in practice).
Even better if both sides can notify: You sleep until you get notified. If it's the consuming side that notifies you, and you haven't seen a notification from the source side since the last time it notified you, then you just give it the cached data. Nothing changed!

So, I don't know what your source and what your sinks actually are – adding that to the question would quite frankly obviously have improved its answerability – but if it is an input device, or if it is something publishing changes via dbus session buses, or if it is something that receives network packets, or even if it is just something that writes files to a directory, that are all things that you can wait for without having to periodically recreate a config file.

Sinks and source are all files (yet). You are right i should have been more specific. I use the WM Fluxbox. And ive written a script that parses my installed Steam library and generates a sub menu for my context menu. And yeah, stupid me did not think of just watching the steam files. But, i in the future i would like my context menus to react to a lot of different thinks, like window information. So, when the menu opens it checks the menu file, and then i would generate it with information from xporp and xdotool.
